# Nested table as condition prevents using index

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, performance, query-performance

The following query joining a subquery does a `TABLE ACCESS FULL` when the master-table uses nested table as condition. When the condition is a simple `=`, the same query does an `INDEX RANGE SCAN` as expected. *(DDL below)*

Why does the query with the nested table not use the index?

```
SELECT m.id, sub.cnt
  FROM m
  LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT d.m_id, COUNT(1) AS cnt -- (+ other functions)
      FROM d
     GROUP BY d.m_id
  ) sub ON ( sub.m_id = m.id )
 WHERE m.id IN ( SELECT /*+ CARDINALITY(tab,1) */ COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( NEW t(1) ) tab )
-- WHERE m.id = 1 -- alternative condition
```

---

Condition `m.id = 1` **uses the index** on `d` as expected:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation           | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 | SELECT STATEMENT    |       |  1000K|    37M|     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  1 |  NESTED LOOPS OUTER |       |  1000K|    37M|     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 2 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN | PK_M  |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  3 |   VIEW              |       |  1000K|    24M|     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  4 |    SORT GROUP BY    |       |  1000K|    12M|     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 5 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN| IDX_D |  1000K|    12M|     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Using the nested table **does not use the index**:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id | Operation                                | Name | Rows  | Bytes |TempSp|Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|  0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |      |  1000K|    39M|      |  185K  (4)| 00:37:05 |
|* 1 |  HASH JOIN OUTER                         |      |  1000K|    39M| 2640K|  185K  (4)| 00:37:05 |
|  2 |   MERGE JOIN SEMI                        |      |   100K|  1464K|      |   30   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|  3 |    INDEX FULL SCAN                       | PK_M |    10M|   123M|      |    0   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|* 4 |    SORT UNIQUE                           |      |     1 |     2 |      |   30   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|  5 |     COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|      |     1 |     2 |      |   29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|  6 |   VIEW                                   |      |   100M|  2479M|      | 4898 (100)| 00:00:59 |
|  7 |    HASH GROUP BY                         |      |   100M|  1239M|      | 4898 (100)| 00:00:59 |
|  8 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                    | D    |   100M|  1239M|      |  571  (95)| 00:00:07 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

---

**DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE m ( id NUMBER);
  ALTER TABLE m ADD CONSTRAINT pk_m PRIMARY KEY ( id );
CREATE TABLE d ( m_id NUMBER );
  CREATE INDEX idx_d ON d ( m_id );

CREATE TYPE t AS TABLE OF NUMBER;

EXEC dbms_stats.set_table_stats ( sys_context( 'userenv', 'current_schema' ),
                                  'M', numrows => 1000 );
EXEC dbms_stats.set_table_stats ( sys_context( 'userenv', 'current_schema' ),
                                  'D', numrows => 10000 );
```

Comment: What if you place the condition inside the derived table, with `WHERE d.m_id IN (...)`? Or if you rewrite without a derived table?

Comment: @ypercube: Duplicating the condition allows to use the index, but I'd prefer a cleaner way. I need several columns from the derived table, what kind of rewrite would you suggest? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need other columns from the `m` table? (the duplication is not need by the way, you can have the condition only inside the derived table as you use `INNER` join. This may lead to better or worse plan.)

Comment: Yes, and in the original query a `LEFT JOIN` is performed instead of the `JOIN`

Comment: If the query is more complicated, then add it in the question. Oversimplifying doesn't help.

Comment: And if the IN subquery is guaranteed to return one value, you can probably run it in advance, save into a temp value and then use it (in one or two places) in your query. There is nothing wrong with splitting the work of a complicated query into 2 or 3 phases.

Comment: I tried to simplify the query as much as possible. I'm sure I will find a way to work around the problem this time, but I'm really trying to figure out why the optimizer does not choose the index when I think it should. The nested table may also contain more than one row, but without the hint the optimizer would assume to get `8192` rows which could justify the full table scan. Thank you for your time so far, really appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm.... this is an interesting one. The Oracle optimizer is a bit of a black box as far as mere mortals like myself are concerned... Jonathan Lewis wrote a 536 page [book](http://www.apress.com/9781590596364) on the topic and that's just the **fundamentals* (and it ain't bedtime reading!).

Two questions.

a) Did you flush the caches before/after each query - maybe the first affects the second - i.e. the optimizer figures out after the first query that it's not worth using an index?

b) What happens if you bump up those numbers in 'M' and 'D'? Does there come a point where it switches back to an INDEX scan? I'm guessing that such a point will come (but see point a)

Just a couple of thoughts - I don't have an Oracle system to hand.

Comment: I'm only creating execution plans, I'm not even executing these test queries. Tried to flush the caches anyway, no difference. Changing the numbers does not affect the plan. `10000` should be more than sufficient to use the index, and the alternative condition does use it.

Comment: Yes, but the alternative condition is a constant - the other is a variable, which as far as the optimizer knows could be anything seeing as you're using that "COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( NEW t(1)" construct. What happens if you create a table T and populate it **before** the query?

Comment: I guess using a table would work, but I'd rather avoid that. I'm telling the optimizer that my nested table only contains one row, using the `CARDINALITY` hint, this is usually sufficient...

Comment: Thanks for the +1. A thought just occurred to me - actually a vague memory from my perusals of the writings of Jonathan Lewis from when I was working with Oracle on a daily basis. I **seem** to remember seeing something about that getting a plan like you're doing is no cast-iron guarantee that that is what the engine will actually do when it comes to running the query against a live system - maybe the plan will be what you want/expect if you have your tables in place and run the query for real? Again, just a thought.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what I'm doing™, but the following, equivalent query seems to do the trick for me (at least, it was equivalent before you had edited your query to use a `LEFT JOIN`...):

```
SELECT m.id, sub.cnt
  FROM m
  JOIN (
    SELECT d.m_id, COUNT(1) AS cnt -- (+ other functions)
      FROM d
     WHERE d.m_id IN ( SELECT COLUMN_VALUE FROM TABLE( NEW t(1) ) )
     GROUP BY d.m_id
  ) sub ON ( sub.m_id = m.id )
```

Which will give me:

```
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                  | Name  | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                           |       |       |       |    31 (100)|          |
|   1 |  NESTED LOOPS                              |       |     1 |    39 |    31   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   VIEW                                     |       |     1 |    26 |    31   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    HASH GROUP BY                           |       |     1 |    15 |    31   (7)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                           |       |     1 |    15 |    30   (4)| 00:00:01 |
|   5 |      SORT UNIQUE                           |       |     1 |     2 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   6 |       COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|       |     1 |     2 |    29   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  7 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN                      | IDX_D |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)|          |
|*  8 |   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                        | PK_M  |     1 |    13 |     0   (0)|          |
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

I did a manual push-down of the predicate in question into the derived table. I will add this lack of functionality in the CBO to the list of expected push-down-operations that don't work as expected (like a push-down of any predicate into a derived table with `UNION`)

Oracle - A device whose mystery is only exceeded by its power!

Comment: `(+1)` Thanks, but unfortunately I need to do a `LEFT JOIN`, so this won't solve my problem. Edited my question (sorry that I did not think about the difference it makes for this problem). Anyway, right now I have worked around the problem by **duplicating** the condition within the derived table and some comments to make the intentions clear. Not pretty, but at least it works. Further suggestions still very appreciated...

Comment: @PeterLang: No problem, it'll work just the same way: just add `OR d.m_id IS NULL` in the derived table (see my update). I'd avoid duplicating the in-memory table. If it gets large, the overhead of binding the variable to the SQL engine twice will become non-negligible.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand your suggestion, there are no entries with `d.m_id IS NULL`, but there are entries in `m` for which no `d` exists...

Comment: @PeterLang: I shouldn't edit my questions that early in the morning... Sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be something wrong here: the 0 cost on the index full scan is suspicious and if I had to guess I would say that you're missing something: probably the stats on the index. This in turn leads the optimizer to believe that it can run the FULL INDEX SCAN "for free" and goes on with a suboptimal plan.

This could also be a rounding error problem, since there is very little data (1k tiny rows, probably fits in a single block!). So either there is some stats missing, or too little data to be meaningful. Interestingly, if we run your test with a large sample (say 1M rows), the optimizer is happy to go with an index scan.

If we insert some data instead and do a standard stats analyze, we find a more logical plan (11.2.0.3):

```
SQL> INSERT INTO m (SELECT ROWNUM FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1e3);
1000 rows inserted
SQL> INSERT INTO d (SELECT ceil(ROWNUM/10) FROM dual CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1e4);
10000 rows inserted
SQL> BEGIN
  2     dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(USER, 'M', CASCADE => TRUE,
  3        method_opt =>'FOR ALL INDEXED COLUMNS SIZE 1' );
  4     dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(USER, 'D', CASCADE => TRUE);
  5  END;
  6  /
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed
SQL> EXPLAIN PLAN FOR
  2  SELECT m.id, sub.cnt
  3    FROM m
  4    LEFT JOIN (
  5      SELECT d.m_id, COUNT(1) AS cnt -- (+ other functions)
  6        FROM d
  7       GROUP BY d.m_id
  8    ) sub ON ( sub.m_id = m.id )
  9   WHERE m.id IN (
 10     SELECT /*+ CARDINALITY(tab,1) */ COLUMN_VALUE
 11       FROM TABLE( NEW t(1) ) tab
 12  );
Explained
SQL> SELECT * FROM table(dbms_xplan.display);
PLAN_TABLE_OUTPUT
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Plan hash value: 2820970863
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                                | Name | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                         |      |     1 |    32 |    31
|*  1 |  HASH JOIN OUTER                         |      |     1 |    32 |    31
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                           |      |     1 |     6 |    22
|   3 |    SORT UNIQUE                           |      |     1 |     2 |    21
|   4 |     COLLECTION ITERATOR CONSTRUCTOR FETCH|      |     1 |     2 |    21
|*  5 |    INDEX UNIQUE SCAN                     | PK_M |     1 |     4 |     0
|   6 |   VIEW                                   |      |  1000 | 26000 |     8
|   7 |    HASH GROUP BY                         |      |  1000 |  4000 |     8
|   8 |     TABLE ACCESS FULL                    | D    | 10000 | 40000 |     6
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```